# How to place text over the image in pre formated area in id card?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on id card project and I have a data into MYSQL db and a id card blank image in PHP page with fixed size.

Now I need to place MYSQL db data into the image finally I need to get id card with all valid data.

I tried:

```
<body>
<div class="image_holder">
    <img src="bg2.jpg" /> 
    <div class="overlay"> </div>
</div>

<div>NHS SUB</div>   
</body>
```

and csss

```
.image_holder {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color:rgba(34,70,118,0.7);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[please check this image i need place text in this format id card layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrOVN.jpg)

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Your `overlay` class actually allows you to place text over an image but why is it empty? Are you expecting NHS SUB to be placed over your image?

Comment: text is placed on image but not at fixed area where i wand to place for example i need to place name data beside Name collom and Designation data beside desg area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

---

```css
.wrapper {
  height: auto;
  height: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image_holder {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #ccecec;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*background-color: rgba(34, 70, 118, 0.7);*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FE9D86;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 90px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="image_holder">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_paris.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:40%;">
    <div class="overlay">
      <pre>Content over image</pre>
    </div>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image_holder">
    <div class="overlay">
      <pre>NHS SUB</pre>
    </div>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please check image i am getting text as it is showing but i need to place text in area where the data need to be in id card like name = Name address = Address and DOb= 20.09.1979 etc in this card

Comment: Okay, when I answered, the sample picture wasn't there. Will update my answer soon.

Comment: @rado I have updated my answer. Are you trying to achieve something like this?